# Is there a name for this "repeating" behavior of vector in R?

Tags: r, repeat

I noticed that a lot of R hackers do something like this:

```
> matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5),nrow=5,ncol=10,byrow=FALSE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3
[4,]    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4     4
[5,]    5    5    5    5    5    5    5    5    5     5
```

Basically, if the size of a vector(in this case 5) is shorter than the size of the "container" that it is put into, in this case, a matrix(with the size of 5 x 10 = 50), it will repeat itself until it fills the container. I think this is absolutely neat feature of R, which makes a lot of R codes very succinct.
Is there a name for this? and a documentation about this?

I noticed this pattern from the following code snippet from(http://training.bioinformatics.ucdavis.edu/docs/2012/05/DAV/lectures/gene-expression-analysis/gene-expression-analysis.pdf). The function basically takes the data matrix and performs a [quantile normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_normalization)

```
quan.norm<-function(x,quan=0.5){
  ##x: p by n data matrix, where columns are the samples.
  norm<-x
  p<-nrow(x)
  n<-ncol(x)
  x.sort<-apply(x, 2, sort) ## sort genes within a sample
  x.rank<-apply(x,2,rank) ## rank genes within a sample
  ## find the common distribution to be matched to:
  qant.sort<-matrix(apply(x.sort,1,quantile, probs=quan),
                    + p,n,byrow=FALSE) #***<----- HERE ***

  ## match each sample to the common distribution:
  for (i in 1:n){
    norm[,i]<-qant.sort[x.rank[,i],i]
  }
  return(norm)
}
```

I added *** in the comment to see where this pattern occurs. I was shocked by the succinctness of the implementation of rather involved algorithm

Comment: Its called recycling.

Comment: ...R calls it [recycling](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#The-recycling-rule), and some people find it repugnant.

Comment: ... but we're not that kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was mentioned in comments it is called recycling rule.

From R Intro:

> Vectors occurring in the same expression need not all be of the same
>   length. If they are not, the value of the expression is a vector with
>   the same length as the longest vector which occurs in the expression.
>   Shorter vectors in the expression are recycled as often as need be
>   (perhaps fractionally) until they match the length of the longest
>   vector. In particular a constant is simply repeated.

Check this link [R manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#The-recycling-rule)